Excel losing focus after running the workbook open macro
I use Win 10. Excel 365.
I have a simple code (removed all other steps to isolate the issue) where on opening the workbook (1) there is a reminder message, (2) activates a certain sheet.
My issue: First time after rebooting the computer, if I go through Windows Explorer and click on the file (to open), macro gets executed but after acknowledging the reminder message Windows Explorer screen comes to the front. If I close the Excel file and open again (thru Explorer) all works fine, and Excel sheet is in front.
If I open the file going through Excel (after rebooting either by clicking on the last file or browsing through directories), all works well.
If I open Explorer after rebooting and then open the file directly from Excel, all works well. Excel screen remains in front.
My code on Thisworkbook sheet is:
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Sheet1.Activate
    Sheet1.Range("G10").Select
    
    MsgBox "Remember to update Production Volume"
    
End Sub

There are no codes on other sheets. No macros on this workbook. I have a few macros on Personal.xlsb (for formatting numbers, columns etc. and they require execution. No auto execution)
I have repaired Excel and then Office, but it did not make any difference.
Can someone please help?
Expect Excel screen in front after opening the workbook

Remove Sheet1.Activate, it is superfluous

Did you experience this behaviour with just this file or with other files as well?

Hi Siddharth, Thanks for the response. I just created a new file. The same result.

Hi Tarik, thanks for the response. Reason for Selecting Sheet1 is On opening the workbook, I do some other tasks on Sheet2. For simplicity I have removed all those steps so that it is easy to focus on the issue.

Can you try to add ThisWorkbook.Activate as the first command in Workbook_Open?

Thanks Doc Brown. I tried but no change in the outcome. I just wonder whether it is something on my computer that is causing this. This happens only on the first time after rebooting. Subsequent times, it works perfectly fine.
